# Regex to validate hypen(-) at start and end of the string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I'm validating a string("-test-") whether it contains hypens(-) at start and end of the string using regex. So i found an regex to restrict hypen at start and end of regex.

```
/^(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-' ]+[^-]$/i
```

This regex was validating as expected when the string contains more than one char("aa") with or without hypen. But its not working as expected when i'm simply passing one character string("a") without hypen.

And also these need to allow special characters and alphanumeric characters like "$abcd&". Need to restirct oly hypen at start and end of the string.

Could you guys help out of this..

Comment: Just change the `+` to `*`

Comment: Use `/^[a-zA-Z0-9' ]+(?:-+[a-zA-Z0-9' ]+)*$/i` or `/^(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-' ]+$(?<!-)/i` / `/^(?!-|.*-$)[a-zA-Z0-9-' ]+$/i`

Comment: @CertainPerformance  *Just change the `+` to `*`* is a wrong solution because `[^-]` matches any char but `-`.

Comment: How about this regex: `^-(.+)-`    [Check example here](https://regex101.com/r/JQZBQ9/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Seems to work with everything I tried https://regex101.com/r/ZH5yXn/2

Comment: If you want the string to start and end with a word character: [`/^\b[a-z\d' -]+\b$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/Zi3wyp/1). (this would also forbid `'` and space at start or end).

Comment: /^(?!-)[\w-' ]+$(?<!-)/i.test('@gs-ss-s@') is returning false. it should allow special characters along with alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @CertainPerformance And that is the problem, it works with [`foo§`, too](https://regex101.com/r/ZH5yXn/3).

Comment: @CertainPerformance the string may contains special characters also. So even the string contains special chars it need to validate only hypen at start and end of the string.

Comment: Another variant for only disallowing hyphen at start/end: [`/^(?!-)[a-z\d' -]*[a-z\d' ]$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/Zi3wyp/2)

Comment: @crazyarun You don't mention those special characters that should pass like `@` anywhere in question. Would be great if you update the question.

Comment: @ bobblebubble  i updated my question. Can u please suggest based on that.

Comment: @crazyarun In comment you mention `@`, in question `$`, `&`. Please list all the special characters in question, that need to be allowed.

Comment: is it possible to allow all special and alphanumeric characters instead of adding special char specfically

Comment: This means to allow any character but just disallow hyphen at start/end? [`^(?!-).*[^-]$`](https://regex101.com/r/Zi3wyp/3)

Comment: @bobblebubble Yes...U r right ... thats my expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow any character but only disallow hyphen at start and end:

```
^(?!-).*[^-]$
```

- `^` [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) of string
- `(?!-)` [look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if there is no hyphen
- `.*` match [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
- `[^-]` match one character, [that is not](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a hyphen
- `$` at the end

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Zi3wyp/3)

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you have matches a string that consists of at least 2 chars because `[a-zA-Z0-9-' ]+` needs 1 char to match and `[^-]` requires another char to be present.

You may revamp the lookahead to also fail a string that ends with `-`:

```
/^(?!-)(?!.*-$).+$/
       ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/23DZlU/5)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!-)(?!.*-$)` - negative lookaheads that fail the match if the string starts with `-` or ends with `-`
- `.+` - any 1 or more chars other than line break chars (use `[\s\S]` to match any char)
- `$` - end of string.

An unrolled version for this pattern would be

```
^[^-]+(?:-+[^-]+)*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/23DZlU/6)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^-]+` - 1 or more chars other than `-`
- `(?:-+[^-]+)*` - 0+ sequences of

  - `-+` - 1+ hyphens
  - `[^-]+` - 1 or more chars other than `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: ^[a-zA-Z0-9' ]+(?:-+[a-zA-Z0-9' ]+)*$ it's working. But when the string contains special char it's not working as expected.

Comment: @crazyarun It is working, at least with plain text. Are you sure the problem is not with `'`? Please make sure you do not run the regex against a string with entities instead of plain text characters.

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9' ]+(?:-+[a-zA-Z0-9' ]+)*$/.test('abc&') It's returning false. Please run this in your browser console.

Comment: @crazyarun Your initial regex does not account for `&` and `$`. If you need it, add it to the character class, `/^(?!-|.*-$)[a-zA-Z0-9&$' -]+$/` or `/^[a-zA-Z0-9&$' ]+(?:-+[a-zA-Z0-9&$' ]+)*$/`.

Comment: is it possible to allow all special and alphanumeric characters instead of adding special char specfically.

Comment: @crazyarun Use `.` instead. `/^(?!-|.*-$).+$/`

Comment: @crazyarun Use `/^(?!-)(?!.*-$).+$/`

Comment: @crazyarun Unrolled one is `^[^-]+(?:-+[^-]+)*$` - please share the strings you test against so that we could check the suggested solutions before sharing.

Comment: ^[^-]+(?:-+[^-]+)*$   this is working fine...Thanks @wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @crazyarun Both must work, and if you show exact code I could explain more.

Comment: Both are working fine. ^[^-]+(?:-+[^-]+)*$  and also this ^[^-]+(?:-+[^-]+)*$.